# Python: How can i find the count of unique dates from a column

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Model             Order_Date    Units_Sold
0   Blue Widget      2020-06-01     3
1   Green Widget     2020-06-04     4
2   Red Widget       2020-06-04     8 
3   Blue Widget      2020-06-02     3
4   Blue Widget      2020-06-03     5
5   Red Widget       2020-06-03     7
6   Green Widget     2020-06-04     3
7   Red Widget       2020-06-02     5
8   Green Widget     2020-06-01     7
```

Hey guys,
So what I am trying to do is get the count of dates from the unique "order_dates" in Python. So this one is looking at 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-04, so count of 4. I want to be able to save this to a variable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `DataFrame` is named `df`. Then try:

`len(df['Order_Date'].unique())`

The [`.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) function can be used to get exactly 1 instance of each unique value from a pandas `Series` column. Then, you can just take the `len` of that array to get the number of unique values.

Comment: Why don't do `df["Order_Date"].nunique()` instead?

Comment: @HenryYik No reason! I didn't know about that function, indeed that's a better choice.

Comment: Perfect, both of these work! Would upvote but stackoverflow wont let me since im new. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `groupby` like so:

```
count = df.groupby(by=['Model'], axis=0).count()
```